# Time in Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, relative-motion

I have a question about the meaning of time in Lorentz transformations.

When we say that event A for S'  occurs at t', I understand that this ct' is a distance, but I wonder exactly what does it mean.

Is it that S' will see the event when the clock marks in its proper time, t'?, Or  Maybe it's a while until the signal comes?

I am a bit confused because t' is not, in this case, the proper time of S' and I also understand that the events do not come instantly to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observer in the inertial frame $S'$ moving with velocity $v$ with respect to another inertial frame $S$ would see the event occurring at $t'$. Lorentz transformation will give you the corresponding set of coordinates in 4-dimensional space-time from one frame to another.

Suppose, the observer in $S$ frame marks the event at $(x,y,z,ct)$. For an observer in $S'$ moving with velocity $v$ in positive $x$-direction w.r.t $S$ would see the event happening at $(x',y',z',ct')$ and are given by
$$x' = \gamma(x-vt)\\ y' = y \\ z' = z \\ ct' = \gamma(ct - \beta x)$$ where $\gamma = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})}}$ and $\beta = \frac{v}{c}$.